# getting values out of json array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

Hi am having a little from with json array. when i try to get the values out of json array.

**Controller**

```
  $data['payment'] = $this->admin->get_payment_settings();
  $value = $data['payment'][0]->json;

  echo $value['username'];
```

Hi am having a json array in database. using my controller i am getting the filed json. When i do a var_dump($value) array look like this

```
  {"username":"foodi1.lch.co","password":"FBUEWQH6X4D","signature":"AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bZnWKgr9on9AmTuhyd4MVq","currency":"CAD"}
```

i want to get each value out of this array.

```
 echo $value['username'];
 echo $value['password'];
```

When i try to do this i get the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'username'
Filename: controllers/administrator.php

Line Number: 620
```

Can some one help me to get the values out of json array. tnx..

Comment: `$value=json_decode($value,true);echo $value['username'];`

Comment: @ShaifulIslam tnx. that fixed my problem. plz add that  as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `$data['payment'][0]` is json string.So you need to decode it.

Try this way

```
$value=json_decode($data['payment'][0]->json,true);//second parameter true will return as array.    
echo $value['username'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the string to a valid array, use `json_decode` as follows:

```
$json = json_decode($value, true);
echo $json['username'];
```